# Hosting EE on GoDaddy.com

Tags: hosting

I'm going from hosting my site on Media Temple to hosting with Go Daddy. Everything should be 100% working, but it's just loading a blank page. They said the hosting and PHP index file are working on their end, that "there must be something in the code" that needs to be updated to tell it to display. Before, I went in and changed the database name and login info to match what I setup with Go Daddy, but do I need to update any reference lines or redirect anything? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Open index.php file at root and replace `$debug = 0;` with `$debug = 1;`. Now see if you are seeing any error message instead of white screen?

Comment: Also remove any htaccess file you might have in place at the moment to see if something in there is causing a white screen

Comment: You may also want to experiment with config.php and add $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"; based on past GoDaddy threads I've read