# URL segmentation GoDaddy

Tags: url, query, facebook, godaddy

I have a problem with GoDaddy hosting. It seems that URL segmentation is not working, so I get link like this `http://example.com/?/main/url_title` and I need link like this `http://example.com/main/url_title` because when I share content on FB instead of link `http://example.com/?/main/url_title` , FB through sharer sees this `http://example.com/?%20main%20url_title`  because of question mark.
I need to solve this problem. Either on GoDaddy somehow or somehow in FB url.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've heard of this issue before, where the host forces query strings.

http://ee2docs.com/urls/remove_index.php.html#exceptions

Look under that reference and scroll down to the area referencing query string forcing. You apparently need to change this rule in your EE installation root's `.htaccess` file to match this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If that doesn't do it, could you expand on your set up (EE version, are you hosting on a sub-domain, other environment attributes that could affect this, etc..)?

**Edit**

Couple of reference answer to check out also:

[Hosting EE on GoDaddy.com](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16625/hosting-ee-on-godaddy-com)

[Strange hosting questions in regards to godaddy and index,php](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/strange-hosting-questions-in-regards-to-godaddy-and-index-php)

Comment: @DonRhummy Glad I provided some info to help solve your issue! Props to my sources, I'm just a excellent Googler some times.